# Get correct records based on column from union which are used in join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

This select is used as `left outer join` in package:

```
 SELECT * (SELECT db1.id, db2.value, db1.discount, 2 AS attr_number FROM database1 db1
      JOIN database2 db2 ON db2.db1_id = db1.id
    WHERE db2.value = 1
    UNION
    SELECT db1.id, db4.value, db1.discount, 1 AS attr_number FROM database1 db1
      JOIN database4 db4 ON db4.db1_id = db1.id
    WHERE db4.value = 1) WHERE id = 225
```

He returns me this records:

```
|ID           |VALUE             |DISCOUNT          |ATTR_NUMBER       |
|-------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|225          |1                 |50                |2                 |
|225          |1                 |50                |2                 |
|225          |1                 |40                |1                 |
|225          |1                 |40                |1                 |
|225          |1                 |40                |1                 |
```

So i need to take `attr_number` row in consideration and fetch records based on that field.

As you can see, the `attr_number` row value could be only 1 or 2.

Per this example, records exists with both values, in this case we need to return only where `attr_number = 1`(because it exists), so this is an example what he should return:

```
|ID           |VALUE             |DISCOUNT          |ATTR_NUMBER       |
|-------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|225          |1                 |40                |1                 |
|225          |1                 |40                |1                 |
|225          |1                 |40                |1                 |
```

As you can see, he "removed" records where `attr_number = 2` and returning only where it's 1.

In other case, if select do not return records where `attr_number = 1`, he returns all other records, in this situation it would be where `attr_number = 2`. This is an example what he should return in this case:

```
|ID           |VALUE             |DISCOUNT          |ATTR_NUMBER       |
|-------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|225          |1                 |50                |2                 |
|225          |1                 |50                |2                 |
```

Hope my explanation is clear enough.

Comment: Please edit your question to alias your `id`, `value`, and `discount` columns in the query. Which table(s) do those columns belong to?

Comment: You've missed the `WHERE  VALUE = 1` in the second part of the query - is that from db1 or db4? If it's the latter, it's not needed, because you included it in the join condition.

Comment: @Boneist Sorry! Now it should look good.

Comment: If you could add the data for the db1, db2 and db4 tables that would also be helpful. Apologies for stringing out the update requests; that wasn't intentional!

Comment: @Boneist All is fine, but unfortunately i can't because those values are not required. If you are asking it to check if data are equal, then yes, they are. This select is just a sample, so i just wanna make sure i understand how make this magic :)

Comment: I want to see where the duplication comes from. Is there one row in db1 and multiple rows in db2/db4, or vice versa? I don't care about anything other than the columns and data used to generate the results of the query. This would help us to generate an efficient query.

Comment: @Boneist That is totally fine. That comes from `database2` and `database4` witch returns me for witch salary it should apply the discount. The salary id is now shown in the query(its unique), `database2` is used before button press in the system and `database4` after, that's why i need to make a check if records with `attr_name = 1` exists, that means was button pressed or not.

Comment: On a side note: This is a weird query ("give me the db1 rows as often as they have a match in db2 or db4"). One would normally rather just select each row once along with a count. And `database1` etc. are strange names for *tables*. The database is the entirety of all tables :-)

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using by the way?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yeah, i will keep this is mind, but the original names of the tables are not equal this as the select script. Can't provide you with original select as also it will blow your mind out. Its too long.

Comment: Oracle -  10.2.0.5.0.

Comment: This is a very old version (10.2 was released in 2005). You may want to upgrade to benefit from all the approvements made since then :-)

Comment: Heh, that would be awesome, but this is not to me. Working in a company witch supports some government projects, not so easy to migrate whole database and front-end to newer version, plus they are not wishing to. So we do not have any choice.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. There is one more thing I'd like to point out here: Don't use `UNION` when you only need `UNION ALL`. Which leads me to: how do you get duplicate rows with `UNION`? That should not be possible. Seems you made a mistake when simplying the query for us.

Comment: Nope, `UNION` is correct. Select should eliminate duplicate rows.

Comment: But all your results, current and desired, do show duplicate rows.

Comment: Not really, i have not added 1 more row, witch has salary_id and it's unique for this records.

Comment: Then you should add that salary column to your examples, so that we don't draw false conclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RANK` to rank your results and only keep the best rows (i.e. those with the lower `attr_number`).

```
select db1.id, 1 as value, db1.discount, dbx.attr_number
from database1 db1
join
(
  select db1_id, attr_number, rank() over (order by attr_number) as rn
  from
  (
    select db1_id, 2 as attr_number from database2 db2 where value = 1
    union all
    select db1_id, 1 as attr_number from database4 db4 where value = 1
  )
) dbx on dbx.db1_id = db1.id and dbx.rn = 1
where db1.id = 225;
```

Comment: Great, will try! Maybe you could suggest one more option? :). `attr_number` is a fictive column, it do not exists in any of the tables, it's only in select to understand in witch step the record was added(this is just in case if you missed it).

Comment: As you can see, `attr_number` is a fictive column in my query, too :-) As to other options: Try this one first. Then come back, if you have issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 `CTE`s, one for each of your unioned queries and then use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WITH 
  cte1 AS (
    SELECT db1.id, db4.value, db1.discount, 1 AS attr_number 
    FROM database1 db1 JOIN database4 db4 
    ON db4.db1_id = db1.id
    WHERE id = 225 AND value = 1
  ),
  cte2 AS (
    SELECT db1.id, db2.value, db1.discount, 2 AS attr_number 
    FROM database1 db1 JOIN database2 db2 
    ON db2.db1_id = db1.id
    WHERE id = 225 db2.value = 1
  )
SELECT * FROM cte1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cte2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte1 WHERE attr_number = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your message, but unfortunately i cant use `WITH` in this case. Select in totally is really big and hard, so with `WITH` and `left outer join` package completed for an hours. But still, thank you for you solution!

Comment: @Viktor the CTEs do not add any burden to the requirement. On the contrary EXISTS in the 2nd query will return fast and the 2nd CTE in case there are 1s in the 1st query will also return fast without any results.